# How do i get the menu options menu to appear in ViewPager Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-optionsmenu

I have a FragmentActivity that has a ViewPager in it and need an options menu in the action bar at the top of the screen. The calls to `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` in the Fragments that I am adding to the ViewPager never gets called and so the options menu is never created and no action bar is shown.

I have added `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` to the `public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the Fragments.
I have also tried adding the options menu directly to the FragmentActivity that contains the ViewPager but this does not seem to work either.

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdaptor pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupPageViewer();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setupPageViewer() {
        UIControlSurface cs = new UIControlSurface();
        UIControlSurface cs2 = new UIControlSurface();
        pager = new PagerAdaptor(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.addPage(cs);
        pager.addPage(cs2);
        ViewPager v_pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        v_pager.setAdapter(pager);
        v_pager.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### UIControlSurface.java

```
public class UIControlSurface extends Fragment implements UIEditableListener{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ui_control_surface, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        Log.i("Menu Inflation", "Here i am!");// never logged
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.navi, menu);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navi_enter_edit:
                return true;
            case R.id.navi_cancel:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### ui_control_surface.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` called in the onCreate method of the fragment I would expect the menu to be created but the action bar and options menu never appear. The Fragments appear in the ViewPager as expected, just with no options menu visible.

Comment: `FragmentActivity` doesn't have an `ActionBar` by default, IIRC. Use `AppCompatActivity` instead, though I'm not sure how options menus in `ViewPager` `Fragment`s will work with that.

Comment: Using AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity fixed this for me nicely. Each fragments options menu is recreated when the fragment comes into view which is to be expected. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I was just looking into that, and it does seem that the `Fragment*PagerAdapter`s do take care of hiding and showing the `Fragment`s' menus appropriately. Nifty. Good to know. Cheers!